# Empty exception on calling method

Tags: c#, .net, exception, iis, soap

I have following code:

```
public class A: IContract, ...
{
    private B b = new B(); 
    // contract method
    public string MethodA(string p1, string p2)
    {
        Log("Start");
        SomeObject obj = CreateObj(p1, p2);
        Log("Before Send");
        string result = b.SendToExternalSth(obj);
        // do sth
        return result;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string SendToExternalSth(SomeObject obj)
    {
        Log("BEGIN");
        string a, b;
        a = proxy.Send(obj);
        // do sth
        Log("End");
        return a;
    }
}
```

After line with `Before Send` is executed I got `System.Exception` with empty message, and exception's stack trace is pointing to line with closing `}` for `SendToExternalSth` method.

Do you have any ideas why it is happening?
I should mentioned that:

- this happening only on production environment (works locally and on test env.),
- code is in c# - .net 4.0,
- This code is part of soap web services code (`MethodA` is an soap action and `SendToExternalSth` method is internal method of some other class) hosted under IIS 7.0,
- I am building it with 'any cpu' option,
- I am deploying `Debug` build on production env,
- Both production and test envs are 64bit windows 2008 r2 sp1,
- .net 4 framework is installed with the same version on both of them,
- There is lack of Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack component on production server, comparing to test env, but currently I am not able to install it there.

Please tell me if some more information is needed to solve this issue, I will be more then happy to provide you it.

Comment: I take it your production environment is running a `Release` build? Try deploying a `Debug` compile and see if you get more/better information along with better line number matching.

Comment: I've already changed build type to `Debug` on production environment, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Maybe try wrapping those method bodies with their own try/catch/log. Maybe it's an issue with _whatever_ is catching the failure higher up.

Answer (score 0):

I've written some more debugging code and changed compilation option several times. After next deploy to production this error didn't occur. I think that was some compilation issue related to `Any CPU` option, but this is just wild guess.

Comment: Please tell me if I did good answering to myself or I should just vote for my question deletion.